# Where is OpenCV's getGaussianKernel method's formula for sigma coming from?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gaussianblur

I noticed that in the OpenCV documentation for [`getGaussianKernel`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#Mat%20getGaussianKernel(int%20ksize,%20double%20sigma,%20int%20ktype)), `sigma` is calculated using this formula:

```
sigma = 0.3*((ksize-1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8
```

Where is this formula coming from? Is this just some approximation that the OpenCV  authors came up with?